# Overriding global type in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, global-variables, react-typescript

I am using two third party typescript library. Both of them are exposing same named global variable using Window interface. Both of them are exposing different methods on that variable.
For example:

1st library is having abc.d.ts
Which exposes, Test variable as global

```
global {
  interface Window {
    Test: {
      A: () => void;
      B: () => void;
      C: () => void;
    };
  }
}
```

2nd library is having pqr.d.ts, which also exposes Test variable as global,

```
global {
  interface Window {
    Test: {
      P: () => void;
      Q: () => void;
      R: () => void;
    };
  }
}
```

I would like to use both libraries and all the functions provided by it (A,B,C,P,Q and R). But, at a time I am getting option of single library only.
Can anyone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `Test` into its own interface. That will allow you to extend as needed. So:

// Lib 1:

```
global {
  interface Test {
      A: () => void;
      B: () => void;
      C: () => void;
  };
  interface Window {
    Test: Test
  }
}
```

// Lib 2:

```
global {
  interface Test {
      P: () => void;
      Q: () => void;
      R: () => void;
  };
  interface Window {
    Test: Test
  }
}
```

## More

Essentially your interface `Test` is going to be extendable the same way as the predefined interface `Window`.